# filter by checkbox value javascript not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I'm trying to filter my page by a checkbox value. That way whenever the value exist in a specific row it will filter that row. The problem with my code is the if checked isn't even firing. I know this because the console log message test is not showing up. I don't get any syntax errors in the console but its not seeing that the check box has been checked. I'm a noob at JavaScript. When the checkbox is checked shouldn't the following code fire?

```
var $row = $("#data tr"),
    $filter_poweron = $("#poweron");

if($filter_poweron.checked) {
console.log('test');
    var filterText_poweron = $filter_poweron.val().toLowerCase();
    $row.each(function () {
        var $row_d = $(this);
        $row_d.toggle($row_d.text().toLowerCase().indexOf(filterText_poweron) > -1);
    });
}

<br><input type="checkbox" id="poweron" value="1O">PoweredOn <input type="checkbox" id='poweroff' value="0F"> PoweredOff
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if($(filter_poweron).is(':checked') {
console.log('test');
    var filterText_poweron = $filter_poweron.val().toLowerCase();
    $row.each(function () {
        var $row_d = $(this);
        $row_d.toggle($row_d.text().toLowerCase().indexOf(filterText_poweron) > -1);
    });
}
```

Comment: `:checked` should be `':checked'`

Answer (score 4):

`$filter_poweron` is a jQuery object. jQuery objects don't have the [`checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/checked) property.

You can get the `checked` property of the DOM element using [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/):

```
var $row = $("#data tr"),
    $filter_poweron = $("#poweron");

if ($filter_poweron.prop('checked')) {
    console.log('test');
    var filterText_poweron = $filter_poweron.val().toLowerCase();
    $row.each(function () {
        var $row_d = $(this);
        $row_d.toggle($row_d.text().toLowerCase().indexOf(filterText_poweron) > -1);
    });
}
```

There are *other* ways to see if a checkbox element is checked:

```
$filter_poweron[0].checked;
$filter_poweron.is(':checked');
$filter_poweron.filter(':checked').length;
```

Answer (score 0):

use the jquery change event and check if its checked or not

```
$(filter_poweron).change(function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        //Do stuff
    }
});
```